# Grails - Render to gsp template from gsp page

Tags: templates, grails, render, gsp

I created template by name (_editBKS) location: /views/products/_editBKS.gsp). When i try to render from the gsp page i'll be ending up with an error.

> Blockquote Error 500: Error processing GroovyPageView: Template not found for name [editBKS] and path [/products/_editBKS.gsp] at /WEB-INF/grails-app/views/products/editProduct.gsp:36

```
g:render template="editBKS" (this is the 36th line in the editproduct) 

Even i tried <g:render template="/products/editBKS"
```

This is way i was rendering to the template.

Any idea why the script is not being rendered?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you attempting to render this template? e.g. Include the code that is rendering it in your question.

Comment: I was trying to render <g:render template="editBKS">

Comment: Have you tried it without the leading slash? `<g:render template="products/editBKS"/>`

Comment: it should be <g:render template="/products/editBKS"/>  If that doesn't work, then it's not in the path you said it was /views/products/_editBKS.gsp or the file name is misspelled.  It would also be a little useful if you provided the context of file that is including this template.